# Scaling heatmaps in R by row and column

Tags: r, heatmap

Hopefully, this post is appropriate for CV and won't be closed.

I have a non-symmetric matrix $M_{K \times K}$ comparing a new statistic, $\delta$, my colleagues and I developed and tested on a variety of $K$ species. $\delta$  ranges between 0 and 1, inclusive.

I've computed $\delta$ for all species pairs. Thus if there are 3 species $\{A, B, C\}$, we can have $\{(A, A), (A, B), (B, A)\}$ and so on. The value of $\delta$ for comprising a species to itself is 1.0.  However, in my case $M_{ij} \neq M_{ji}$ for a species pair $(i,j)$.

I'd like to produce a heatmap of $M$ but am wondering how to best normalize the heatmap (either by rows or columns) via the `scale` argument to `heatmap()`. By default, `scale = "row"` and the R documentation Details section suggests this is appropriate for genomic plotting. However, the two heatmaps (scaled by rows and columns, respectively)
look very different. Note, I've removed the dendrograms and sorted the names alphabetically for easy comparison.

```
scale = "row"
```

[image]

```
scale = "column"
```

[image]

The white sections of the plots correspond to a given species whose comparison to all other species results in $\delta$ = 1. Clearly, interpretation is problematic since the white areas don't agree between the two plots.

The `scale` argument can also be be set to `scale = "none"`

[image]

The above plots correspond to $K$ = 48 where $M$ contains 1330 `1s`, in addition to intermediate values.

The R documentation does not give any references to learn more about the impact of `scale`. My case is also different in that the same variables are being plotted on the $x$ and $y$ axis; typically, the variables are different.

**Does anyone have experience with setting the best scale when the plotted variables are identical, or can point me to some good references?**

I've found this website

https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-normalize-and-standardize-data-in-r-for-great-heatmap-visualization/

but would like something more authoritative if possible.

Comment: Why would you want to normalize at all?  Shouldn't that depend on what this statistic means and why you're visualizing it?

Comment: I thought about not nomalizing at all (i.e., just using the `None` heatmap), since the values of the statistic are all on a common scale (0-1). However, normalizing by both rows and columns revels some interesting biological patterns and suggests I could present all three heatmaps. I guess what I'm after more is a book reference (or similar) on the effects of different scalings.

Comment: I don't know anything about these species, so this might not be relevant but 58% = 1330 / 2304 of the similarity statistics are 1. This suggests that the statistics is not very sensitive. Take a look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3081066/9566484) about visualizing a dissimilarity matrix. If you try out one of the projection techniques suggested there, you may discover that a bunch of species are projected very close to each other (little discrimination). This might be something interesting to discuss in your paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By default, `scale = "row"` and the R documentation Details section suggests this is appropriate for genomic plotting.

That's the case for situations in which you have fundamentally different types of rows and columns. For example, gene-expression data might be arranged with samples along rows and expression levels of genes in columns. Then scaling by row makes sense if the overall measured level of expression differs among samples; scaling in that case illustrates how *relative* expression of genes might differ among samples. That then could be combined with clustering by genes (columns) or samples (rows) to find groups of biological interest in a heat map.

Your situation is quite different. Your rows and columns are the same: they represent the same set of species. And you're not using any clustering results, so your use of `heatmap()` is essentially  a front end to the R `image()` function.

"Scaling" by row (resp. column) in this function just means that the values *within each row* (resp. column) are transformed to have zero mean and unit standard deviation before mapping onto colors. That doesn't make a lot of sense for values that already are restricted to be between 0 and 1 and thus already have a reasonable natural scale.

Scaling also poses a problem when all of the values are identical in a row (resp. column): then the standard deviation is 0 and scaling will be unreliable, producing `NA` values. I think that's what's going on with the white bars in the top 2 images.

Furthermore, as "$M_{ij} \neq M_{ji}$ for a species pair $(i,j)$," when you scale by rows you get different results than when you scale by columns, as you demonstrate. And you lose the expected behavior with a measure where all the $M_{ii}=1$: they would be expected to have the same color as they have the same value.

The difference in the appearance of row versus column scaling comes from the asymmetry represented by $M_{ij} \neq M_{ji}$. You might interpret that visual difference in terms of the asymmetry that you have built in to that statistic. As you don't explain the source of that asymmetry, I don't know that a book or reference can tell you any more about the visual difference than you already can infer from the fact that you have set things up such that $M_{ij} \neq M_{ji}$.

The setting `scale = "none"` is the natural choice here, as it maps the range of colors onto the range of actual values of $\delta$. The default color setting only has 12 values, and you seem to have a lot of values that are very close to 1, so you might want to allow for a larger number of colors (or use a different mapping of colors to $\delta$ values) to show more distinctions at the top of your scale.

When there is a square matrix with identical row and column names like this I dislike the `heatmap()` behavior of having the identity line (here, with all values equal 1) run from bottom left to top right. If that bothers you (or your reviewers), you can use `heatmap(t(myMatrix), revC = TRUE, ...)` to have that run in what I find to be the usual way, from top left to bottom right.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with `scale = "none"` then, since $\delta$ already ranges from [0, 1]. Also using in `heatmap()`, obviously `symmetric = FALSE` by default. In my case that's what is needed since I have $M_{ij} \neq M_{ji}$.

Comment: @compbiostats although the matrix _values_ are asymmetric you might still specify `symmetric = TRUE`. That will ensure that the _order_ of the row names and the _order_ of the column names are the same. In general with `heatmap()`, the separate clustering by rows and columns will lead to different orders in general between rows and columns. That said, you seem to be providing some other arguments  (like `Rowv=NA, Colv=NA`) that prevent clustering by rows or columns, so the `symm` argument won't matter. The `symm` argument doesn't enforce symmetry of the matrix entries.

Comment: Yes, I removed the row and column dendrograms using `Rowv = NA` and `Colv = NA` since we think the heatmaps would be better served in the context of "look-up tables", rather than enforcing any particular ordering dictated by the dendrograms (hence why the current ordering is alphabetical). Interestingly `symm = TRUE` does differ from its default when  `Rowv` and `Colv` are both `NA` for my case, which is a bit confusing. I'll try to add more colours as you suggest to see what signal comes out.

Comment: To add to your suspicion regarding the need for more colours in the heatmap, doing `table(myMatrix)` tells me there are 24 `0s` and 2665 `1s` in my dateset.

Comment: @compbiostats you must have more than 48 species in your dataset, as 48*48= 2304. If multiple entries in your matrix have the same value, then they should all have the same color. If you want to draw more attention to the entries that are different from `1`, you might want to remove the default `rev = TRUE` setting in the `col` argument that gets passed to the `image()` function. Then the `1` values will be light colored and the non-`1` values progressively darker as they move toward `0`.

Comment: Yes. My mistake. $K$ = 48 and there are actually only 1330 `1s`.

Comment: @compbiostats the answer now explains the white bars in the top 2 images: NA values produced by `scale` when all values in a row (column) are the same.